# Creating an admin user in Devise on Rails beta 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ok, I'm probably going to feel quite dumb when someone answers this one with a simple thing that I'm missing but... here goes:

I've got a brand new app on rails 3 beta and I'm using devise for the authentication. I've run all the comments and everything is working perfectly at the moment. I've created a user role and an admin role (following these instructions: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role) and I've registered myself as the first user but how to do I register or create an admin role user? The directions from the devise guys setup the admin role to not be registerable but I'm unsure how you're supposed to create the admin if you can't register?!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yup. I feel dumb.

If anyone else is having a similarly vapid moment. Just use the rails console to create the admin user:

```
➡ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.0.beta3)
irb(main):001:0> admin = Admin.create! do |u|
irb(main):002:1* u.email = 'sample@sample.com'
irb(main):003:1> u.password = 'password'
irb(main):004:1> u.password_confirmation = 'password'
irb(main):005:1> end
```

That will do it. Now just visit your admin sign in path and sign in.

Comment: The vote up was not referring to the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: In reality, how much of a rails site is actually managed using the rails console?  You know, those minor things, a flag field here and there?

Comment: Probably a terrifying amount is managed through the console. I know I use it all the time. But I guess we should be thanking @dhh for creating such a great way to access our Rails apps.

Comment: As of latest Devise and ActiveAdmin, use AdminUser.create! instead of Admin.create! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 14):

What you are really trying to do is create seed data.
A more standard way to do this would be to add your seed users (and roles, if you are storing them) to db/seeds.rb

For exmaple in db/seeds.rb:

```
roles = Role.create([{name: 'super_admin'}, {name: 'staff'}, {name:'customer'}])
users = User.create([{email: 'super@test.com', first_name: 'super', last_name: 'admin', password: '@dmin123', password_confirmation: '@dmin123', role: roles[0]}])
```

Then run:

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

This may not apply to Devise (but I believe it will), but in general if you want to seed an admin user but don't want to store your admin password in source control, you can do something like this...

```
@user = User.find_by_email("admin@email.com")

unless @user
  # We are going to bypass both our assignment protection and validation
  # so we aren't storing the password in source control.
  #
  # This doesn't replace the need to change the password occasionaly, both
  # on the site and in source control.
  @user = User.create do |u|
    u.name = "Admin User"
    u.email = "admin@email.com"
    u.password_digest = "$2a$10$DUv/IUiLB34jhi3j4Z8MwwcaDlBmFe3rvcdXSzPKLzBOAMmD53UqW"
  end

  @user.save(:validate => false)

  # TODO make the user an admin
end
```

You can create the user locally with the password you want to find the password_digest.

Comment: does devise use md5 to digest password?

Answer (score 3):

@Stewart You are correct. Using an admin flag in the user model is acceptable and can still co-exist with many authorization options.  Take a look at the Ability class in the cancan docs for an example of how this might look:

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Having multiple authorization models can be useful if the functionality is really different or if the requirements for authorization, such as adding subdomain to the authkeys, is different.

Another approach is to add a HABTM roles relationship to your user.  Here is a nice tutorial by Tony Amoyal:
http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

try appending /sign_in to your admin path, whatever you set it to...mine is

http://yoursite.com/admin/sign_in?unauthenticated=true

Comment: oops you likely didn't use :authenticable.  Try this page for help on overriding the admin views:  http://wiki.github.com/fortuity/subdomain-authentication/tutorial-walkthrough

Comment: No, I didn't use :authenticatable when setting up the admin model with devise, like I said, I was using the tutorial that divise has on their github page. I would prefer not to use subdomains if I can help it...

Answer (score 0):

There is convenient way for populating tables - [db/seed.rb](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) file. Just add the script for creating users in it and run:

```
rake db:seed
```

Below you can see example of `User` model with `email` and `username` fields:

```
# Inserting default security users
users = {

    admin: {

        username: 'admin',
        email: 'admin@gmail.com',
        password: 'adminpass',
        password_confirmation: 'adminpass',
        is_admin: true
    },

    administrator: {

        username: 'administrator',
        email: 'administrator@gmail.com',
        password: 'administrator',
        password_confirmation: 'administrator',
        is_admin: true
    }
}

users.each do |user, data|

  user = User.new(data)

  unless User.where(email: user.email).exists?
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Note, that devise validations are applied here.

[Here](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html) you can find more examples of using the `seed.rb` file and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) is the rayn's rails cast.