# Devise: How to create a private admin role?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a simple Rails 3 blog app that needs an admin user so I can restrict creating and editing blog entries to the admin. I've used devise before, but only for users that are public and can be created by anyone. I don't want the ability to create an admin to be publicly accessible. How should I configure devise to be able to have an admin user?

### Update:

After creating an Admin model, you might want to know [how to create an admin that can log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708417/creating-an-admin-user-in-devise-on-rails-beta-3/2752839#2752839) (since you won't be able to register them on the front-end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [HOWTO](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role) in Github. There are basically two options:

1. Create a separate admin model
2. Add a admin attribute to the existing user model

I personally prefer option 1 for larger applications which tend to have different views for admins and normal users. For smaller apps I would recommend option 2.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know which approach to take, so a second opinion always helps. =]