# I can`t create admin user on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using `Rails 3.2.13` and `Devise`.

Devise is working fine but I can`t create`“admin”` user.

I followed this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role#option-2---adding-an-admin-attribute

and added the admin attribute to the users table.

I tried to insert the admin using this topic: [Creating an admin user in Devise on Rails beta 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708417/creating-an-admin-user-in-devise-on-rails-beta-3)

**This is User model:**

```
User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean)
```

And this is my **seed file**:

> user = User.create!(name: "admin", email: "admin@admin.com", password:
>   "admin", password_confirmation: "admin", encrypted_password: "admin",
>   admin: true)

But when I execute `rake db:seed`, active record shows me an error message:

> invalid_record

I don`t know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the information in `seeds.rb` to:

> user = User.create!(name: 'admin', email: 'admin@admin.com', password:
>   'admin123456', password_confirmation: 'admin123456', admin: true)

I wasn't able to insert the User *admin* because password was too short.